# Instance of a fragment from activity displaying it

Tags: android, fragment

I have a `ViewPager` and `TabLayout` in one activity. I am using `ViewPagerAdapter` in order to display my three fragments.

Now I want to call some function from one fragment. As soon as a button is clicked from the activity, the list of the fragment should changed. So the error was coming that as soon as I click the button the list element of fragment is null because that element is not declared in activity but is declared in fragment. So how to take the whole instance of a fragment so that the list could be easily changeable. I have used:

```
(PatientHistoryFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" 
    + R.id.myRecordsViewPager 
    + ":" 
    + mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

but it is returning `null`.

Could anyone help me with it?

Comment: Please post more code and error logs

Comment: View.OnClickListener filter = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PatientHistoryFragment patient=(PatientHistoryFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.myRecordsViewPager + ":" + mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
            patient.filterShow(MyRecords.this,MyRecords.patientPersonUUid);
        }
    };

Comment: there is function of filter in patienthistoryfragment which i have to call from myrecords activity but i am receiving null error in patient variable

Comment: Please edit your question and put code and logs.

Comment: got my solution thanx . Was doing some silly mistake (Not silly though) . Thankyou once again.

Answer (score 0):

Problem that was coming was that the adapter which i added in viewpager was :-

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

where my `ViewPagerAdapter` was :- `class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

due to which my variable

```
(PatientHistoryFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.myRecordsViewPager + ":" + mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

was returning null . But i changed my ViewPagerAdapter class to :-
`class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter` (In short i removed State) and now it works. Thanks everyone :)